# Записать переключение изображений одним скриптом

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу немного упорядочить этот весь бардак в коде, так как изображений станет больше и занимать они будут прилично места. Вот собственно код:

```
<img alt="Фото" src="/big-img-1.jpg" class="gphoto" onclick="_bldCont1($ID$, this.getAttribute('idx'));" id="ipreview" idx="0" title="Кликните для увеличения изображения" itemprop="image">

<img alt="Превью: 1" src="/small-img-1.jpg" class="gphoto active" onclick="var el=getElementById('ipreview'); el.src='big-img-1.jpg'; el.setAttribute('idx',0); $('.gphoto').removeClass( 'active' ); $( this ).addClass( 'active' ); return false" />
<img alt="Превью: 2" src="/small-img-1.jpg" class="gphoto" onclick="var el=getElementById('ipreview'); el.src='big-img-2.jpg'; el.setAttribute('idx',1); $('.gphoto').removeClass( 'active' ); $( this ).addClass( 'active' ); return false" />
<img alt="Превью: 3" src="/small-img-1.jpg" class="gphoto" onclick="var el=getElementById('ipreview'); el.src='big-img-3.jpg'; el.setAttribute('idx',2); $('.gphoto').removeClass( 'active' ); $( this ).addClass( 'active' ); return false" />
<img alt="Превью: 4" src="/small-img-1.jpg" class="gphoto" onclick="var el=getElementById('ipreview'); el.src='big-img-4.jpg'; el.setAttribute('idx',3); $('.gphoto').removeClass( 'active' ); $( this ).addClass( 'active' ); return false" />
```

При клике заменяется ссылка на основном изображение и прописывается idx, для увеличения в lightbox.

В общем-то, скрипт не очень то и сложный, сейчас пробую его написать однако хотел уточнить последовательность действий. Берем класс .gphoto и по клику выполняем действия прописанные в onclick. Как внутри изображения прописать пусть на большое изображение и его id для увеличения основного изображения? Какие атрибуты для этого использовать, что думаете о "srcset" для ссылки на большое изображений?

Сильно не пинайте. Я пока только учусь.

Comment: 1. А "большое" фото можете быть только одно? 2. А у вас одни и те же классы для больших и маленьких картинок или нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По вашему коду, можно осуществить так:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.gphoto').click(function() {
    $('#ipreview').attr('src', $(this).attr('data-big-img')).attr('idx', $(this).attr('data-idx'));
    $('.gphoto.active').removeClass('active'); 
    $(this).addClass('active');
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img alt="Фото" src="/big-img-1.jpg" class="gphoto" onclick="_bldCont1($ID$, this.getAttribute('idx'));" id="ipreview" idx="0" title="Кликните для увеличения изображения" itemprop="image">

<img alt="Превью: 1" src="/small-img-1.jpg" class="gphoto active" data-big-img="big-img-1.jpg" data-idx="0" />
<img alt="Превью: 2" src="/small-img-1.jpg" class="gphoto" data-big-img="big-img-2.jpg" data-idx="1" />
<img alt="Превью: 3" src="/small-img-1.jpg" class="gphoto" data-big-img="big-img-3.jpg" data-idx="2" />
<img alt="Превью: 4" src="/small-img-1.jpg" class="gphoto" data-big-img="big-img-4.jpg" data-idx="3" />
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Именно то, что и хотел.